# how does turbo chef oven work and technology in it?

Tags: oven

Anyone know exactly how the turbo chef oven works like what technology does it use and how does it supply heat ? I'm interested

Answer (score 1):

From a quick google: It looks to be a combination of 3 different technology, radiant heat, hot air and microwave.

From the turbo chef web site: [Tubo Chef Bullet](https://www.turbochef.com/product/bullet/)

"The Bullet oven uses radiant heat, high-speed air impingement, and side-launched microwave to cook food rapidly without compromising quality."

Air impingement seems to be high pressure, high temperature air jets:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/food-science/air-impingement

[Video describing air impingement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-__KIKsxOBU)